# How to remove similiar values and group it from a text file in c++?

Tags: c++, file, grouping, computer-science

Say I have a text file

```
200     34

34     377

20      2

34     45

200    7

10     63
```

and I want to group it in a way that values of column one are not repeated and contain elements of col 2 like this:

```
200:  34  7


34 :  377 45


20:   2


10:   63
```

How do I do it? I am a beginner programmer and so far I only managed to read the file and print it out like using

```
ifstream inFile;

inFile.open("textfile.txt");

if (inFile.fail()) {
    cerr << "Error opeing a file" << endl;
    inFile.close();
    exit(1);
}
string line;

while (getline(inFile, line))
{
    cout << line << endl;
}

inFile.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Read input into a multimap and then iterate over inputted elements.

```
std::multimap<int, int> m;
int a, b;
while (inFile >> a >> b) {
    m.insert(std::make_pair(a, b));
}
inFile.close();


for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ) {
    std::cout << it->first << ": ";
    for (auto end = m.upper_bound(it->first); it != end; it++) {
        std::cout << it->second << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

But maybe it's easier to think just about a map with a vector:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> m;
int a, b;
while (inFile >> a >> b) {
    m[a].push_back(b);
}
inFile.close();

for (auto i : m) {
    std::cout << i.first << ": ";
    for (auto j : i.second) {
        std::cout << j << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

[Tested on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/HXm7fN).

Your output seems to have keys in reverse order, so you might use `rbegin` and `rend` with reverse iterators to iterate over the map.

Comment: That while loop in your second can be simplified a lot... `while (inFile >> a >> b) { m[a].push_back(b); }`

Comment: Och right, because `m[a]` inserts the key if it does not exists.

Comment: The sample output might also be ordered by first appearance of the key, rather than descending order.

Comment: oh i see! yea a map is easier to understand. Although for the code part of the stringstream inFile , is there a way to not hard code the values? since we assume the values i gave come from a text file

Comment: I used `stringstream` only in godbolt to test. You use `ifstream` in your code.